# Fix date issue in a .csv file with utl_file

Tags: plsql, utl-file, oracle-ebs

I am using `utl_file` to write in a `csv` file. The data includes date columns also. The issue here is

For a single digit day 0 gets removed when the data gets inserted in the `csv` file.
   Eg - date 07-Jun-13 gets inserted as 7-Jun-13, how can I ensure that 0 stays?

I already `to_char` and `concat` "" but still I get single digit date only. The csv file being generated is used by a 3rd party system hence no change can be made in the `csv`.

I am using EBS 12.1.3.

Thanks

PL/SQL code snippet

```
   concat(concat('"',lv_proj_start_date),'"')    ||','||
   concat(concat('"',lv_proj_start_date_plus_1),'"')     ||','||
```

I expect the output for date in the csv like `07-Jun-13`

but in csv file the o/p is `7-Jun-13`.

Comment: Writing CSV files is a bit harder than you might think.  I would recommend using a prebuilt solution, such as [this procedure](https://github.com/jonheller1/data_dump/) I maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both columns are of DATE format, you need to explicitly convert the date into whichever format you desire, e.g.:

```
'"' || to_char(lv_proj_start_date, 'dd-Mon-yy', 'nls_date_language=english') || '","' 
    || to_char(lv_proj_start_date_plus_1, 'dd-Mon-yy', 'nls_date_language=english') || '",'
```

N.B. I have also converted your `CONCAT` function calls to use the concatenation operator `||`, as this is much easier to read. I've also combined text strings where possible.

I have also used the optional third parameter of `to_char()` to explicitly set the date language to be English, which makes it NLS independent.

A final note: do you absolutely have to output the dates with 2-digit years? 4-digits are preferred nowawdays, post Y2K!

---

ETA: Here's an example showing that the output is correct:

```
DECLARE
  lv_proj_start_date DATE := to_date('07/07/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
  lv_proj_start_date_plus_1 DATE := lv_proj_start_date + 1;

  v_str VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  v_str := '"Testing","' || to_char(lv_proj_start_date, 'dd-Mon-yy', 'nls_date_language=english') || '","' 
                          || to_char(lv_proj_start_date_plus_1, 'dd-Mon-yy', 'nls_date_language=english') || '"';

  dbms_output.put_line(v_str);
END;
/

"Testing","07-Jul-19","08-Jul-19"
```

Comment: Thanks Boneist, let me try and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Boneist, I have another doubt. The user is asking whether the csv file generated fulfills the below properties.                                                                                                     CSV Properties: 
Character Encoding: UTF-8
Quote Char: “ (Double Quote)
Separator: , (Comma)
Header Line: 1 (Mandatory)
Escape Char: Backslash
Multi select separator: Semicolon.   Can you let me know how can we ensure and check on this?

Comment: the character encoding will depend on the character set of your database. As for the others, you have the ability to output each line with the required delimiters, etc...

Comment: Tried it and it did not work, in csv it is showing as 7-Jul-13 only.